# How to pass parameter not related to model by form_for on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to pass parameter not related to model by form_for on rails.I want to pass 'address' data, that is not related to product model, from view to controller. The following is my code, however it returned the next error. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
>   ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..5)):

**products_controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  ~~~~
  def transfer
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def transfer_done
    my_address = params[:my_address]
    wallet = Wallet.find_by(address:my_address)
    redirect_to root_url
  end
  ~~~~
end
```

**transfer.html.erb**

```
<% provide("transfer") %>
<p>
  <%= form_for @product, :url => {:action => 'transfer_done'} do |f| %>
   <div>
     <%= check_box :my_address %> <---Error occurred here.
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: `check_box_tag`  it but for address neeed check box ?

Comment: No, I only need to pass parameter. Another reference (written in Japanese) told this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try `<%= text_field_tag :my_address %>` inside your form

Comment: @toshikaseda : Mark it as answer if it resolved your problem

Comment: It seems that it cannot mark it as answer before it has taken 8 minutes. I mark is as answer now.:)

Comment: This assumes you're happy with an out-of-scope `:address` attribute in your params hash

Comment: This does not work for me AR complains _unknown attribute_